# completely removed node js not cant able to install again

Tags: node.js, installation

I just removed nodejs completely by using following command
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}`. now i again trying to install the nodejs after successful installation by typing `node -v` or `npm -v` it showing no such a file or directory  `bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`. please help me to install nodejs LTS version again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you installed node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove all the instances of nodejs. For a fresh new install. 
Since your's is not working use

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Then install `nvm` which is the best tool to install nodejs and npm.

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

Update your bash

```
source ~/.profile
```

The below code will install the node version 6.11.5
Or check the github page of **node version manager(nvm)**

```
nvm install v6.11.5
```

Now hopefully your system will work with node without any issue